# Помогите пожалуйста с кнопкой

Tags: objective-c

Хочу сделать в приложении кнопку с таким же эффектом как на этом сайте http://prankota.com/ , но уже несколько недель не могу найти как её сделать. Если кто-нибудь знает помогите пжл, кнопка может просто увеличиваться в размере при нажатии.  Язык приложения Objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы увеличивалась в размере при нажатии это надо у кнопки перехватить событие UIControlEventTouchDown  и внем сделать какую -нибудь анимацию увеличения картинки, можно через изменение frame, а можно и через CoreAnimation, по моему даже в штатном примере было что-то такое. Как вариант если такая кнопка не одна - создать свой-класс наследник от UIControl который будет делать это все автоматом

Comment: Ты можешь научить меня делать такой класс за деньги? (WM)

Comment: нет, у меня сейчас со временем беда, я потому и ссылку на конкретный пример не привел - искать некогда

Comment: Дай мне знать когда появится время. ВК: http://vk.com/kullshov